# PhpMyAdmin "No data received" on import

Tags: php, import, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to upload CSV file to a PhpMyAdmin service hosted by Byethosting. I have imported things before and have had no issue. 
I had a spreadsheet that is over 150,000 rows, which I split into 8 pieces. each having roughly 20,000 lines each [image: Chunks]

When trying to import these files into a new table, it sends me to /import.php "No data received" being displayed. 
I have no access to the php.ini file.
Are these files still too big?
What can be done?

Comment: did you tried with other extensions ? like .sql ?

Comment: I have tried with .ods. I have also looked into .sql but the file originates as a csv, I have looked into converting from CSV into .sql but have had no luck in that process